# MongoDB Trigger - Match Expression

Tags: mongodb, triggers

I wrote the trigger to listen for the update operation type on the collection1. This is the huge transactional collection and number of updates are high per secs. This caused the trigger often goes to the 'Suspended' status.

I thought of implementing the 'Match Expression' option under the ADVANCED section on the Trigger creation page. Here, we can write the match block to ensure the trigger will fire only if match this filter. The problem here is that I am not able to use any mongodb clause/operator here.

**Working Code:**

```
{
      "updateDescription.updateFields": {
        "status": "blocked"
      }
    }
```

**Not Working Code:**

```
{
          "updateDescription.updateFields": {
            "status": {"$in":["blocked","non_blocked"]}
          }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how your match expression should work:

```json
{
    "$or": [
        {
            "updateDescription.updatedFields": {
                "$eq": {
                    "status": "blocked"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "updateDescription.updatedFields": {
                "$eq": {
                    "status": "non_blocked"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```